# How do I add and call a custom Java class inside a jBPM Process?

Tags: java, jbpm

I have a local jBPM 7.33 with a simple process. At one point in the process, I need to generate a PDF file.

I want to do it by creating a very basic Java class that is run in a Task. The class would get variables from the process scope, generate the PDF and save the generated blob (or filesystem path) as a process variable.

How do I add a custom class and then call that class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that's what we call it `WorkItemHandler` , your java class will be a customized jbpm task

1. First of all [install jbpm in eclipse](https://www.javatpoint.com/jbpm-eclipse-plugin)
2. Create a jBPM project in eclipse (tick Build the project using Maven)
3. create a java class that implements `WorkItemHandler`. it will be in this format.

   ```
    package com.example;
    import org.kie.api.runtime.process.WorkItem;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.drools.core.process.instance.WorkItemHandler;
    import org.kie.api.runtime.process.WorkItemManager;

    public class WorkItemTest implements WorkItemHandler {

        @Override
        public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
            workItem.getParameters().toString();

            /**Input Variables***/
            String stringVar = (String) workItem.getParameter("stringVar");


            /***
             * 
             * 
             * YOUR CODE
             * 
             */

            String msg = "done";

            /**Output Variables in a HashMap***/
            Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            resultMap.put("Result", msg); //("name of variable", value)
            manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), resultMap);
        }

        @Override
        public void abortWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
            System.out.println("Aborted ! ");

        }

    }
   ```
4. Build a jar file of this project (with maven).
5. From the workbench, go to Artifact, upload the jar
   click on this icon, then artifacts
   [image]
6. from the settings of your project, go to dependencies, and add from repository the uploaded artifact
   [image]
7. from the settings of your project, go to Deployments / Work Item Handler and add a new work Item Handler : type its name and how to instantiate it (`new com.example.WorkItemTest()`)
   [image]
8. Finally, go to the Asset "WorkDefinitions" , define your work item (so you can see it in the workflow designer tool) as follow

```
  [
    "name" : "WorkItemTest",
    "parameters" : [ //inputs
        "stringVar " : new StringDataType(),
    ],
    "results" : [ //outputs
        "Result" : new ObjectDataType(),
    ],
    "displayName" : "WorkItemTest",
    "icon" : "defaultservicenodeicon.png"
  ]
```

9. you can now find this task in "service tasks" of your workflow designer tool (refresh before)

Comment: Thank you again Bashir, you have been extremely helpful to me! I did not understand steps 5-8 though. In my console I manually did `mvn clean install` and that created the jar, but I can't find what is the workbench / Artifact - I tried looking in Eclipse and in the jBPM. I'm using jbpm 7 with the business central. I did get the WorkItemDefinition to show in editor and I even tried adding the class directly into the project that has the process, but when I try to execute, it tells me "Could not find work item handler for WorkItemTest". Can you still help me with those?

Comment: you need eclipse only to develop the workitem. everything else is done in the business central. So,  in step 5, as it's shown in the screenshot, you have to click on that icon in the navbar (on top of screen), then you choose artifacts , later you'll have a button upload, you click on it to upload your jar file. I hope this step is now clearer

Comment: you didn't understand steps 5 & 8 , or from step 5 to 8?

Comment: PS: I edited the answer, because I mistaken the step in which I should post the screen shot, (it was on step 6, while it is in step 5)

Comment: Ah, I understand now! Like an idiot, I was looking confused at the "Artifact repository" and not "Artifacts". Also I had to update the jBPMS version defined in the Eclipse default project pom.xml to get the execution to work. Amazing help, thank you so much!