# How to call a process from different project using subprocess in jbpm 7

Tags: jbpm

to call a process of different project using subprocess below configurations are needed. Please tell how to do this changes in jbpm 7.0+ version workbench.

Is there any option to create kbase & ksession without having them as default.

Create Reusable Project(ProjectA,ProjectB), which will include Reusable sub processes(processA,processB).Make sure that the kbase and ksession configured for this project will not be default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WorkItemHandler`, a custom task that you can create which can behave the way you want. This, will be like a subprocess in this WorkItemHandler, you call for the other process from an other project using remote java API.

- take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60654953/how-do-i-add-and-call-a-custom-java-class-inside-a-jbpm-process/60655805#60655805) to see how to use `WorkItemHandler`
- and [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/jbpm-remote-service) to see more about jbpm remote service

code that you can use

```
package com.example;
import org.kie.api.runtime.process.WorkItem;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;    
import org.drools.core.process.instance.WorkItemHandler;
import org.kie.api.runtime.process.WorkItemManager;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeEngine;
import org.kie.api.runtime.process.ProcessInstance;
import org.kie.remote.client.api.RemoteRuntimeEngineFactory;

public class WorkItemTest implements WorkItemHandler {

    @Override
    public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
        RuntimeEngine jbpmEngine = RemoteRuntimeEngineFactory.newRestBuilder()
                                    .addUrl(new URL("http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/"))
                                    .addDeploymentId("com.abc.sasa:1.0"); //put here your DeploymentId
                                    .addUserName("admin")
                                    .addPassword("admin")
                                    .addTimeout(180)
                                    .build();
        KieSession ksession = jbpmEngine.getKieSession();         
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        int value = xxx..;
        params.put("var",value); //here you put the parameters you want to pass to the process
        manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), resultMap);
        ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess("project.workFlow",params);
    }

    @Override
    public void abortWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
        System.out.println("Aborted ! ");

    }

}
```