# JBPM Service Task assignments input from config

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm, business-process-management, drools-guvnor

I have JBPM process where I have add Service Task Rest. In the assignments inputs I want to set url through config file and not directly in the source field.

[image]

I am researching 3 days but still I cant find it.

Is there any option to set the url value like this:

> http://{ip-address}/{port}/update

As you can see in the example above ip-address and port should be read from a config or property file.

> The next part is just to check is everything okay.

Can I achieve the result like this:

```
    Config config = new Config();
    

    /** Output Variables in a HashMap ***/
    Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    resultMap.put("Result", msg); // ("name of variable", value)
    resultMap.put("url", "http://" + config.getProperty("ip") + config.getProperty("port") + "/update");
    manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), resultMap);
```

> NEW EDIT

Maybe I wrote it a little bit confusing but like this the whole url need to be in the config and what I want is only ip and port to be read from config and to to write in the source like this manually: http:// (wrote by me manually) + ip : port (read from config) / update (wrote by me manually). So as I wrote above, I want only ip and port values from config. That is why I wrote them as {ipVar}:{portVar} above.

> New edit:
> Thank you for the detailed answers. Maybe I am writing it confusing so I will explain this picture:
> [image]

you see my point was to only get ip and port from config and anything else what user want to write because there can be another endpoints...

for example:
http://{ip}:{port}/create/user/bashir
or
https://{ip}:8080/asd/update

I want to get ip and port as variables from config and to use it if I need in some assignment, for this case URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two solutions:

- First one: To create your own Rest Task, it is what we call WorkItem which consist of developing your own task in which you consume your REST API the way you want. take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60654953/how-do-i-add-and-call-a-custom-java-class-inside-a-jbpm-process/60655805#60655805) to have an idea on how do we create WorkItem.
- Second one: You need to create a WorkItem (a custom task) that you call it just before the Service Task Rest which will only import your data from a config file and assign the imported values into global variables. And then, in the Service Task Rest, you have to put in the Source field the name of variable for each input

I hope my answer was clear and helpful. This is how I always do.

Edit: you have to change your code as follow

```
Config config = new Config();


/** Output Variables in a HashMap ***/
Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
resultMap.put("Result", msg); // ("name of variable", value)
resultMap.put("url", "http://" + config.getProperty("ip") +":"+ config.getProperty("port"));
manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), resultMap);
```

in WorkDefinitions:

```
[
    "name" : "WorkItemTest",
    "parameters" : [ //inputs
        "stringVar " : new StringDataType(),
    ],
    "results" : [ //outputs
        "url" : new ObjectDataType(),
    ],
    "displayName" : "WorkItemTest",
    "icon" : "defaultservicenodeicon.png"
]
```

then, you go to **variable definition** and define a variable called **url** and **finalURL** of type String as follow (it's in french language)

[image]

Later, you draw your task and put output as follow:

[image]

now your url from config file is assigned to a the variable url, now you need to concatenate the url with the endpoint (ip:port/update). To so you need to add a script task in which you will add this line of code:

```
kcontext.setVariable("finalURL",url+"/update"); //this will assign the url + "/update" to the variable finalURL
```

So last step now, in the screenshot that you shared, for the url, you choose from the combobox the variable named finalURL, as follow

[image]

Comment: Hello Bashir, thank you for the fast answer. If i change the config file do i need to rebuild and upload jar again? This is for the first solution. And about the second solution: I still need to create jbpm project in java and etc?

Comment: if you change the config you don't have to re-upload the new jar (and this is for both solutions), you do so only if you change something in your code. For the second question, yes, you have to create a workitem in java (just like the first solution) and then upload the jar, which will be a task in your workflow that only import data from config file and assign them into variables that will be used in the default Service Task Rest (use variables in source field, like in your screen shot). To summarize, in both solutions you need to create WorkItem, the difference is only in the logic.

Comment: I think the first solution wont suite my final result because I don`t have global variables. 
I want to do it like this: When I go in the assignments to write: http://{ipVar}:{portVar}/update

Comment: I think the second solution will work for me. Because I need to use global variables to use it in the Service Task Rest inputs assignments and to write in the Source field of url this:  http://{ipVar}:{portVar}/update