# How to connect datasource to data input assignment's source in rhpam?

Tags: java, postgresql, jbpm, business-process-management, redhat-bpm

I have created datasource and a table which contains id and the email id of the user. I created a Email Task and I wanted that the "To" field as shown here should come from the database for the specific user id.
How am I going to perform this?

[image]

Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suggest here is quiet simple. Try to create a [WorkItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60654953/how-do-i-add-and-call-a-custom-java-class-inside-a-jbpm-process/60655805#60655805) in which you get the email address and assign it into a global variable of your process, later, in the E-mail task you use this address.